# I just started using methods. This is a template and I'm confused on how to do the methods. Can someone show me how to do what is being asked?

Tags: java, string, methods, static, program-entry-point

I'm not sure how to add the methods that is wanted as this is my first program not doing everything in a main. It's super confusing to me. I have no idea how to make a method and only vaguely what it entails or how to return. Could anyone help me out with this code?

Edit::
I did the code thanks to the provided tips. However, I can't seem to get the last two methods to work. I feel as though shift char is to be used withing String shift but i dont know how. What i have here compiles and runs but the last output is "String shifted by one letter is 'Nztizhzqtz'" when i input My Shy Gypsy which correctly shifts every letter forward 1 letter in the alphabet but takes the spaces away, why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        String s = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nNumber of Spaces in the string = " + countSpaces(s) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Number of E's in the string = " + countChar(s, "E") + "\n");
        System.out.println("Number of Stars in the string = " + countChar(s, "*") + "\n");
        System.out.println("Does string contain vowels? " + anyVowels(s) + "\n");
        System.out.println("String reversed = " + reverse(s) + "\n");
        System.out.println("String shifted by one letter is " + shift(s)  + "\n");
    }

    // method to return the number of spaces in a String
    public static int countSpaces(String input) {
        int spaces = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0;i<input.length();i++){
            if(input.charAt(i) == ' '){
                spaces++;
            }
        }
         return spaces;
    }

    // method to count the number of instances of
    // a particular character in a String
    // the method will return the total of upper and lower
    // case instances if it is a letter
    public static int countChar(String input,String findStr) {
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        findStr = findStr.toLowerCase();
        int num = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0;i<input.length();i++){
            if(input.charAt(i) == findStr.charAt(0)){
                num++;
            }
        }
        return num;

    }

    // method to detect whether a String contains a vowel or not
    // must include call(s) to countChar
    // returns true or false
    public static boolean anyVowels(String input) {
        int num = 0;
        num = countChar(input, "a")+countChar(input, "e")+countChar(input, "i")+countChar(input, "o")+countChar(input, "u");
        if(num >  0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    // method to return the reverse of a String
    public static String reverse(String input) {
        String reverse = "";
        for (int i = 0;i<input.length();i++) {
            reverse = input.charAt(i) + reverse;
        }
        return reverse;    
    }

    // method to return a character shifted one place in the alphaber
    // a becomes b, b become c etc. z becomes a
    // A becomes B, B becomes C etc. Z becomes A
    // all other characters are left unchanged
    public static char shift(char input) {

        char shiftedChar = 'a';
        shiftedChar++;
        //for (int i = 0; i < input.length();i++) {
        //    shiftedChar = input.charAt(i);
        //  
        //}



        return shiftedChar;
    }

    // method to return a String with each letter shifted one place in the alphabet
    // method must include call(s) to previous method
    public static String shift(String input) {

        String shiftedString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length();i++) {
            char a = input.charAt(i);
            if (a != ' ') {
            a++;
            shiftedString = shiftedString + a;
            }
        }







        return shiftedString;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to show some effort before asking a question on SO. Just dumping your homework here is going to result in downvotes and a closed question. Since we're talking about the absolute basics here, you should look for a basic tutorial (I'd recommend the [Oracle Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)).

Comment: I understand your point, and I'm not trying to just ask for someone to do my homework. I just need like an example to help me out. Not trying to be rude, sorry.

Comment: @ChristopherWhitt I gave you some pointers below.

Comment: I didn't take your question as rude. The problem with examples is that they don't usually give you as much information as reading through a proper tutorial. You might be blindly copying code, and when something is a bit different it won't work anymore. It's like trying to build a house and your options are "becoming an engineer" or "just look at the neighbour's house and try to get the same end result". Besides, after reading the tutorials you won't need to come back to ask another question for your next homework (or at least it won't be as broad as this one).

Comment: You're absolutely right. I read through my book on methods even, I just have a difficult time learning it that way. I'll definitely check out the tutorials though.

Comment: There's no *easy* way to learn. I suggest you learn to like reading, as the "I learn by doing" is just a codename for "I learn by trying things and asking others to help me". You can't rely on others' help being available always.

Answer (score 0):

I see the teacher has left you the skeleton of the methods so I will help you out with the first one.

```
public static ________ countSpaces(________) {


    }
```

Here the first underlined part is what you want the method to return (i.e. do you want it to return text (String) or an integer (int)). Look up datatypes for Java. Hint: what it should return is in the comments above the method.

The second underlined part (in brackets) is what you wish to pass to the method when you want to use it. So if the method needs the number 10 in it to do some sort of calculation, and return some sort of text, one example would be:

```
public static String countSpaces(int 10) {
       //do whatever necessary here

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is quite helpful, so the data type goes afterwards, gotcha. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem - if you are happy with the answer, upvote/accept it - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do the first one.

```
// method to return the number of spaces in a String
public static ________ countSpaces(________) {

}
```

What needs to be added is this

```
// method to return the number of spaces in a String
public static int countSpaces(String input) {
   int spaces = 0;
   // Do the magic counting here
   return spaces;
}
```

Now the method takes a String as input and returns an integer as output.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't provided all the method implementations. Some are left for the questioner to implement. However, below are some hints which can be useful -

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        String s = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nNumber of Spaces in the string = " + countSpaces(s) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Number of E's in the string = " + countChar(s, "E") + "\n");
        System.out.println("Number of Stars in the string = " + countChar(s, "*") + "\n");
        System.out.println("Does string contain vowels? " + anyVowels(s) + "\n");
        System.out.println("String reversed = " + reverse(s) + "\n");
        System.out.println("String shifted by one letter is " + shift(s)  + "\n");
    }

    // method to return the number of spaces in a String
    public static int countSpaces(String input) {
         return input.split(" ",-1).length-1;
    }

    // method to count the number of instances of
    // a particular character in a String
    // the method will return the total of upper and lower
    // case instances if it is a letter
    public static int countChar(String input, String findStr) {


    }

    // method to detect whether a String contains a vowel or not
    // must include call(s) to countChar
    // returns true or false
    public static boolean anyVowels(String input) {

    }


    // method to return the reverse of a String
    public static String reverse(String input) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(input);
        return sb.reverse().toString();
    }

    // method to return a character shifted one place in the alphaber
    // a becomes b, b become c etc. z becomes a
    // A becomes B, B becomes C etc. Z becomes A
    // all other characters are left unchanged
    public static char shift(char input) {

        char shiftedChar = '';
        // TODO - code to shift the char

        return shiftedChar;
    }

    // method to return a String with each letter shifted one place in the alphabet
    // method must include call(s) to previous method
    public static String shift(String input) {

        String shiftedString = null;

        //TODO shit the char for each char in a String

        return shiftedString;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Christopher Whitt - see if this helps.

Comment: I think the other answers already demonstrated what to do. Finishing 90% of his homework won't help him learn. It'll just teach that there's always someone who will do the majority of homework when it's dumped here.

Comment: Think you've given too much there.

Comment: removed the implementations.